# How can I find values with more than 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, decimal

I am validating data and trying to find if there are any values in a single column (allowed_amount) with more than 2 decimal places (24.1145678, 234.444, -1234.09012).

```
with t1 as (
  select (allowed_amount - round(allowed_amount,2)) as ck
  from export_core_report_client_output
  where runid = '0c7c2d34-6cc3-43b0-ae4b-4bd8f4bddfb0'
) 
select min(ck) as min, max(ck) as max from t1
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried to use to accomplish this?

Comment: with t1 as (
select (allowed_amount - round(allowed_amount,2)) as ck
from export_core_report_client_output
where runid = '0c7c2d34-6cc3-43b0-ae4b-4bd8f4bddfb0'
)
select min(ck) as min, max(ck) as max from t1

Comment: `select * from t where round(amount,2) <> amount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use this formula:

```
SELECT
    num,
    CASE WHEN 100*num - CAST(100*num AS int) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS field
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

For example, for the value `24.1234`, the above formula computes:

```
2412.34 - 2412 = 0.34 > 0
```

But for `24.12`, we get:

```
2412 - 2412 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Charindex to do that, supposing the allowed_amount column is varchar or nvarchar

`select len(substring(allowed_amount,charindex('.',allowed_amount)+1,len(allowed_amount))) from export_core_report_client_output`

This will give you a count of decimal values after and then you can use the same statement in where clause to scrutinize like:

`select len(substring(allowed_amount,charindex('.',allowed_amount)+1,len(allowed_amount))) from export_core_report_client_output
where len(substring(allowed_amount,charindex('.',allowed_amount)+1,len(allowed_amount)))> 2`

any questions fire up in the comments